# httpClient post request call does not succeed in windows.unload event angular

Tags: angular, typescript, browser, httpclient, onbeforeunload

I want to send post request from my client to server while user close tab or browser window i am using  'windows.unload'or 'windows.beforeunload' event when i invoke my call in this event it does't succeeded, windows closed before getting response how do i do this, i have tried some thing here is my code

This is 'onbeforeUnload' event

```
window.onbeforeunload = ()=>{

  this.store.dispatch<any>(this.mystore.UnLock());
}
```

this is my function in Store

```
UnLock() {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
      dispatch(this.resetTimer());
      return this.dataService.Locks('/unlock').subscribe(
        (data: any) => {},
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          if (err.error instanceof Error) {
            dispatch(this.errormsg('Client-side error occured.'));
            console.log('Client-side error occured.');
          } 
        }
      );
    };
  }
```

Here is my data service function

```
Locks(url: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpclient.post(url, {
      headers: _headers
    });
  }
```

my browser window is closed before getting response from server, i am stuck in this issue how do i resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

-put this code in bootstrap component

```
export class AppComponent {  
  constructor() {
    window.onbeforeunload = (e)=> {
        this.store.dispatch<any>(this.mystore.UnLock());
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: this does't help me, still getting same issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular, then use `Angular guards` to implement it.

**For this scenario you have to use**

> canDeactive

guard in angular.